# In WPF, how do I apply a ControlTemplate to all Textbox

Tags: wpf

So I am new to WPF and I followed online tutorials to create a controlTemplate for Textbox, I could apply it by manually setting the style but I would like to it automatically to all textbox.

Now I read online for styles, you can simply just remove the Key definition and it will be universal, but I think that only apply to Style and not ControlTemplate, because when I do that, it throw an error saying "All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key association with them"

What do I do?

```
<ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create **default style** like you mentioned and `set default template` inside it so that it gets applied to all textBox. Make sure you place this under `App.Resources` so that it gets applied to textBoxes in all windows. If you want that to be applied on specific window place this under `Window.Resources`.

```
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                     ...
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

i am agree with the way of style. but there is another way,
use **UserControl** with the text box. set all properties to the textbox as need. and simply use any where you want!

Comment: I agree this is a legitimate strategy, too much work for just a test page, but I can see how this is a better way for big projects.